Does overloading between static/instance methods in Java count as overloading?
example:
 class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) { }
  public static void foo(int a ) { }
  public void foo() { }
}

do we consider this overloading in Java or is this something else? (since static vs non-static)

next section of the one I posted in your previous question: JLS 8.4.9. Overloading: "If two methods of a class (...) have the same name but signatures that are not override-equivalent, then the method name is said to be overloaded."

and from JLS 8.4.2: "have the same signature if they have the same name, the same type parameters (if any) (§8.4.4), and, after adapting the formal parameter types of N to the type parameters of M, the same formal parameter types. ... are override-equivalent iff either m1 is a subsignature of m2 or m2 is a subsignature of m1"
